# Serialized form as JSON's field send to ASP.NET controller method and doesn't bind

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'XXXXX',
     data: {
         someField: $("#someField").val(),
         formSerialized: $("#form").serialize()
    },
})
```

And I have controller method:

```
public ActionResult XXXXX(string someField, List<myModel> formSerialized)
{
    ......
}
```

So here's the problem - "someField" is bound without any problems, but "formSerialized" contains 0 items (I expect 2).

But what is interestring,  if I'll create ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'XXXXX',
     data: $("#form").serialize()
})
```

And controller's method:

```
public ActionResult XXXXX(List<myModel> formSerialized)
{
    ......
}
```

Everything is bound fine (I have 2 items in "formSerialized"). How to force ASP.NET to bound data properly in the first case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but  serializeArray() should fix that

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'XXXXX',
     data: {
         someField: $("#someField").val(),
         formSerialized: $("#form").serializeArray()
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you serialise a form it creates a URL encoded string based on the forms inputs. It uses the name attribute as the parameter name.

So when you're serialising your form you're creating the following

```
someField=somestring&formSerialized=formdata&formSerialized=formdata2
```

Which would bind the string and two list values.

The problem with this...

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'XXXXX',
     data: {
         someField: $("#someField").val(),
         formSerialized: $("#form").serialize()
    },
})
```

...is you're binding the url encoded parameters to a parameter so you get the following

```
someField=somestring&formSerialized=someField=somestring&formSerialized=formdata&formSerialized=formdata2
```

Which is invalid as you have formSerialized=someField=somestring in the url

This article explains mvc model binding really well

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Hope this makes sense.